# PHP socket_bind(): unable to bind address [10013]

Tags: php, sockets, udp

I'm trying to make an udp socket connection to a specific hardware, which receives data at port 7715, sends answers to udp port 7714, ports can't be changed. Piece of code below:

```
<?php
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);

if (!socket_bind($socket, '192.168.1.254', 7714)){
    echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
}

socket_connect($socket, '192.168.1.150', 7715);
if (!socket_listen($socket, 5)){
    echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
}

$arr = [0x23, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06];
$checksum = 0x00 - array_sum($arr);
$str = implode(', ', $arr);

$eval = '$buffer = ' . "pack('c*', $str, $checksum);";
eval($eval);

socket_write($socket, $buffer);
```

Firewall disabled, Wireshark shows, that everything is OK:

> 1  0.000000    192.168.1.254   192.168.1.150   UDP 54  65213 → 7715 Len=12
>
> 2  0.005611    192.168.1.150   192.168.1.254   UDP 78  7715 → 7714 Len=36

Somehow, PHP can bind this socket to any udp port, but not to 7714.

> Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [10013]: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
>
> Warning: socket_listen(): unable to listen on socket [10045]: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Find out myself, udp port 7714 was used by other process.